# else statement does not return to loop

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x, while-loop

I have a code that opens a file, calculates the median value and writes that value to a separate file. Some of the files maybe empty so I wrote the following loop to check it the file is empty and if so skip it, increment the count and go back to the loop. It does what is expected for the first empty file it finds ,but not the second. The loop is below

```
t = 15.2
while t>=11.4:
 if os.stat(r'C:\Users\Khary\Documents\bin%.2f.txt'%t ).st_size > 0:  
    print("All good")
    F= r'C:\Users\Documents\bin%.2f.txt'%t 
    print(t)  
    F= np.loadtxt(F,skiprows=0)
    LogMass = F[:,0]
    LogRed =  F[:,1] 
    value = np.median(LogMass)  
    filesave(*find_nearest(LogMass,LogRed))
    t -=0.2
 else:
    t -=0.2 
    print("empty file")
```

The output is as follows

```
All good
15.2
All good
15.0
All good
14.8
All good
14.600000000000001
All good
14.400000000000002
All good
14.200000000000003
All good
14.000000000000004
All good
13.800000000000004
All good
13.600000000000005
All good
13.400000000000006
empty file
All good
13.000000000000007
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documents\Codes\Calculate Bin Median.py", line 35, in <module>
    LogMass = F[:,0]
IndexError: too many indices
```

A second issue is that `t` somehow goes from one decimal place to 15 and the last place seems to incrementing whats with that?
Thanks for any and all help

**EDIT**
The error `IndexError: too many indices`  only seems to apply to files with only one line example...

```
12.9982324  0.004321374
```

If I add a second line I no longer get the error can someone explain why this is? Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried a little experiment and it seems numpy does not like extracting a column  if the array only has one row.

```
In [8]: x = np.array([1,3])

In [9]: y=x[:,0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-50e27cf81d21> in <module>()
----> 1 y=x[:,0]

IndexError: too many indices

In [10]: y=x[:,0].shape
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e8108cf30e9a> in <module>()
----> 1 y=x[:,0].shape

IndexError: too many indices

In [11]:
```

Comment: The decimal place you're seeing is because it's [slowly accumulating a slight error from arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) (especially the subtraction operation 14.8-0.2). You can choose to limit display of decimal places if this is an issue.

Comment: Look at the shape on the numpy arrays coming back

Comment: Look at `x.shape`.  In your input 10 the exception is happening _before_ the shape call.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using try/except blocks.  Something like:

```
t = 15.2
while t >= 11.4:
    F= r'C:\Users\Documents\bin%.2f.txt'%t 
    try:  
        F = np.loadtxt(F,skiprows=0)
        LogMass = F[:,0]
        LogRed =  F[:,1] 
        value = np.median(LogMass)  
        filesave(*find_nearest(LogMass,LogRed))
    except IndexError:
        print("bad file: {}".format(F))
    else:
        print("file worked!")
    finally:
        t -=0.2
```

Please refer to [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) for more details about exception handling.

The issue with the last digit is due to how floats work they can not represent base10 numbers *exactly*.  This can lead to fun things like:

```
In [13]: .3 * 3 - .9
Out[13]: -1.1102230246251565e-16
```

Comment: The file that throws the error is an empty file with zero bytes.

Comment: Then catch that exception as well.

Comment: Do you mean skipping the first file or skipping the first row when you say " but then skipping the first "

Comment: I miss-read your code and thought you were skipping headers when you are explicitly _not_ skipping headers.

Comment: Yes no header skipping

Comment: Any explanation on why the loop does not go back after the second time it reaches the else?

Comment: I still think my initial guess was correct that you have a non-empty file which is badly formatted.  However, you _should_ be doing this with try/except.  It is better to ask forgiveness than permission.

Comment: I checked and the next file in the sequence, the one that throws the error,  is empty and never contained any information. There are only 21 files so I checked them one by one.

Comment: But will try with try/except

Comment: I misread the printout, the files throwing the error are not the empty ones, but ones with only one row.  Do not understand why that is.

Answer (score 2):

To deal with the one line file case, add the `ndmin` parameter to `np.loadtxt` (review its doc):

```
np.loadtxt('test.npy',ndmin=2)
# array([[ 1.,  2.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a user named ajcr, found the problem was that `ndim=2` should have been used in `numpy.loadtxt()` to insure that the array always 2 has dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses ***indentation*** to define `if` `while` and `for` blocks.

It doesn't look like your `if` `else` statement is fully indented from the `while`.

I usually use a full '**tab**' keyboard key to indent instead of '**spaces**'

Comment: It is very strongly discouraged to use tabs.  At least in the scientific python community 4-spaces is the standard.  You should be using and editor that will translate <tab> -> 4 spaces.  And the OP code _is_ indented just with mixed levels.  This is probably due to a mix of spaces and tabs ;)