# IndexError: too many indices. Numpy Array with 1 row and 2 columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I try to get just the first element of an array like this

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([1,2])

a[:,0]
```

I get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ed371621c46c> in <module>()
----> 1 a[:,0]

IndexError: too many indices
```

I would like to find a way to do this while still using slicing because the full code opens and reads many different files using `numpy.loadtxt()` all having two columns which vary from 1 to some N.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your array `a = numpy.array([1,2])` only has *one* dimension: its shape is `(2,)`. However, your slice  `a[:,0]` specifies selections for *two* dimensions. This causes NumPy to raise the error.

To get the first element from `a` you only need to write `a[0]` (a selection for only one dimension is being made here).

---

Looking at your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191240/else-statement-does-not-return-to-loop), if you want to ensure that the syntax `a[:,0]` always works, you could ensure that `a` always has two dimensions. When loading an array with `np.loadtxt` use the `ndmin` parameter, e.g.:

```
np.loadtxt(F, skiprows=0, ndmin=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that in the full code I have many files with varying column lengths so just getting the first element does not work.

Comment: @Surfcast23: I see you've edited your question with some extra details, but I'm not quite sure what you're after. If your arrays only have one dimension (as in your example) `a[i]` will select the value at index `i`. For arrays with two dimensions (rows and columns), `a[i,j]`will select the value in the `j`th column from row `i`.

Comment: Sorry if unclear, my question actually stems from a problem I was having that I asked in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191240/else-statement-does-not-return-to-loop

Comment: @Surfcast23 - Ah, OK, I think I might understand - I've edited my answer with a suggestion (let me know if it's of any use to you or not).

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above, you have a one-dimensional array and you're trying to slice it with two dimensions.

One thing to add, and which I've found very useful in the past, is that numpy allows you easily cast a 1D array into a 2D array (either as a row or column):

```
>>> a = np.array([0,1,2])
>>> a.shape
(3,)
>>> a_row = a[None,:]
>>> a_row.shape
(1,3)
>>> a_col = a[:,None]
>>> a_col.shape
(3,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also struggled with this problem when parsing many input files that can have 1-1000s of rows. However, I am using numpy genfromtxt which doesn't allow you to set 'ndmin', so the solution I came up with is to manually set the array shape equal 1 for arrays with 1 row:

```
>>> arr=np.genfromtxt('file',names=['a','b'],dtype='f4,f4') 
>>> if (np.size(arr) == 1): arr.shape=1
```

The 1 row array now acts like a 1-D array that can be indexed:

```
>>> for i in range(np.size(arr)): print arr['a'][i]
```