# how to read rows of a column from csv file on python?

Tags: python, csv, url

```
activity=csv.reader(open('activity(delimited).csv')
data = np.array([activity])
url_data = data[:, 70]
```

I am trying to extract a column from the CSV file. This column has a list of URLs that I would like to read. However every time I run these few lines, I get:-

IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: you are missing a `)` end of first line.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of **very similar** issues on StackOverflow [[post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036812/indexerror-too-many-indices-for-array)], [[post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199585/indexerror-too-many-indices-numpy-array-with-1-row-and-2-columns)].

For your reference, there is a much cleaner way of achieving this. 
[`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) will suit your requirements pretty well. From the documentation,

> Load data from a text file, with missing values handled as specified.
>
> Each line past the first skip_header lines is split at the delimiter
>   character, and characters following the comments character are
>   discarded.

You would need to do something like this.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('activity(delimited)', delimiter=',')
```

Given that yours is a csv, the delimiter is a `,`.

`my_data` should now hold a numpy [`ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

Comment: I get this error now: ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32